# How can I define a column as 64bit integer using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, integer

I'm creating a table as following:

```
create table SomeTable (
LoginTime int,
someValue 64bit-int
)
```

How can I define the second column as 64bit integer?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 22):

In MySQL, the `BIGINT` datatype represents an 8 byte (64-bit) integer. It can be `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED` which permits (or prevents) negative numbers in the column.

You can read more about all variants of MySQL integer data types [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html). The column attributes are discussed [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html).

Comment: `BIGINT UNSIGNED` or `BIGINT SIGNED`

Answer (score 7):

I assume you are using Sql Server.
You want to use a

```
bigint - signed 64-bit.
```

Comment: i'm using mysql indeed, is bigint ok for mysql?

Comment: Yes (10 more characters to go)